# Is there a way to find out which bitrate HLS stream chromecast is playing?

Tags: video-streaming, chromecast, google-cast, http-live-streaming

I am using default media receiver on Chromecast and am am adding the Google Cast sender app support to chrome/web videoplayer. I need to know which bitrate stream Chromecast is rendering at a given moment for instrumentation purposes. Is there any listener that I could attach to listen for bitrate change events? Or can I poll current selected bitrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in the default/styled receiver; you need to have your own custom receiver and if you do that and use MPL (MediaPlayerLibrary), you can get that information through `getQualityLevel()` method. Note that you can grab the [Cast-Player-Sample](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) which is the reference receiver and update that based on your needs; that is the best starting point for a comprehensive UX-compliant custom receiver.

Comment: Thank you Ali for clarifying this.